# Catching an exception class within a template

Tags: c++, templates, exception, overflow

I'm having a problem using the exception class Overflow() for a Stack template I'm creating. If I define the class regularly there is no problem. If I define the class as a template, I cannot make my call to catch() work properly. I have a feeling it's simply syntax, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    T *stackArray;
    int size;
    int top;

public: 
    Stack(int size) { this->size = size; stackArray = new T[size]; top = 0; }
    ~Stack() { delete[] stackArray; }

    void push(T value)
    {
        if (isFull())
            throw Overflow();
        stackArray[top] = value;
        top++;
    }

    bool isFull()
    {
        if (top == size)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    class Overflow {};

};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Stack<double> Stack(5);
        Stack.push( 5.0);
        Stack.push(10.1);
        Stack.push(15.2);
        Stack.push(20.3);
        Stack.push(25.4);
        Stack.push(30.5);
    }
    catch (Stack::Overflow)
    {
        cout << "ERROR! The stack is full.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the catch (Stack::Overflow) statement.  As I said, if the class is not a template, this works just fine.  However, once I define it as a template, this ceases to work.  I've tried all sorts of syntaxes, but I always get one of two sets of error messages from the compiler.

If I use catch(Stack::Overflow):

```
ch18pr01.cpp(89) : error C2955: 'Stack' : use of class template requires template argument list
ch18pr01.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'Stack'
ch18pr01.cpp(89) : error C2955: 'Stack' : use of class template requires template argument list
ch18pr01.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'Stack'
ch18pr01.cpp(89) : error C2316: 'Stack<T>::Overflow' : cannot be caught as the destructor and/or copy constructor are inaccessible
```

EDIT: I meant
If I use catch(Stack<double>::Overflow) or any variety thereof:

```
ch18pr01.cpp(89) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Stack'
ch18pr01.cpp(89) : error C2310: catch handlers must specify one type
ch18pr01.cpp(95) : error C2317: 'try' block starting on line '75' has no catch handlers
```

I simply can not figure this out. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: On your edit: That's exactly what dark_charlie meant: Don't use the same name for types and variables!

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (const Stack<double>::Overflow & obj)
                 //^^^^^^^^ note this!
```

That is, you've to provide the type also.

Also note that I'm accepting the object as `const` reference so as to avoid copy of the original `Overflow` object!

By the way, why did you make `Overflow` a nested type? What rationale do you have? I don't see any compelling reason to do so. It would be better if you define it outside `Stack` class template.

Comment: I had previously tried using Stack<double>::Overflow, and it did not fix my problem - until I changed my variable name to something different than the class name.  As for why I nested Overflow? That is what my textbook suggested in its example program.

Comment: @Todd: Your class name is `Stack`, and your object name is also `Stack`. Why did you do this? Your keyboard doesn't allow you typing different name?

Comment: No need to be condescending... main() was provided with my textbook, and I was meant to build a template class around it.  I would not have chosen to do that on my own.

Comment: @Todd: You mean your textbook has same name for both type and variable?

Comment: Yep.  And it told me to nest the Overflow() class too.

Answer (score 2):

The point is you should put

```
class overflow;
```

outside

```
class Stack<>
```

since it is a general exception, not type specified.

Comment: also, it should inherit from std::exception.

Comment: Thank you for this bit of advice.  I'm still a budding talent, so knowing proper coding procedures is very important to me.  I will do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify, which template instantiation you are using:

```
try
{
    Stack<double> Stack(5);
    Stack.push( 5.0);
    Stack.push(10.1);
    Stack.push(15.2);
    Stack.push(20.3);
    Stack.push(25.4);
    Stack.push(30.5);
}
catch (Stack<double>::Overflow)
{
    cout << "ERROR! The stack is full.\n";
}
```

If you do not specify the template argument, the compiler is confused because it doesn't know which class to use (for example `Stack<int>` or `Stack<double>`?).

Side note: Try to avoid using same names for types and variables (`Stack` and `Stack` in this example), it makes the readability and bug tracking harder.

Comment: I had used catch (Stack<double>::Overflow) previously to no avail, but when I changed the variable name, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Why would the compiler not be able to determine which one it is? Or perhaps use some RTTI to do it at runtime?